# For $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $\left \lceil \frac{n}{k} \right \rceil=\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \right \rfloor +1 $.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $\left \lceil \frac{n}{k} \right \rceil=\left \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}  \right \rfloor+1 $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $a = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \rfloor$ is the unique nonnegative integer satisfying $n-1 = ak + r$ with $0 \leq r < k$.
This condition on $r$ implies the fraction $\frac{r+1}{k}$ is in the interval $[1/k, 1]$. Therefore,
$$
\left\lceil \frac{n}{k} \right\rceil
= \left\lceil \frac{ak+r+1}{k} \right\rceil
= a + \left\lceil \frac{r+1}{k} \right\rceil
= a + 1 .
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $k\mid n$, then this result is immediate.

Suppose $k\nmid n$, then $\lceil \frac{n}{k}\rceil = 1 + \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$.

Lastly, can you reason why $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac{n-1}{k} \rfloor$.